# How to open the terminal? (Mis-configured the profile)

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am quite new to Ubuntu. (I started to use Ubuntu about a year ago, but I don't know how to use things like terminal well. All I used by console was easy things like `ls` or `cd`, to use gcc.)

Today, I found 'profile' property of the terminal, and I created a new profile. Then, I changed some properties like font color and opacity.

Soon, I found something like 'command', and for test, I set that to `ls`. I closed and re-opened the terminal. However, the terminal terminates right after it appeared. I soon remembered that there was option like **'close right after the command is executed'**.

Therefore, I can't use Gnome Terminal D: ... I found Konsole at Ubuntu software center, but that's just not my style (especially cursor, its position is little weird...).

Question : **How to change the profile of Gnome Terminal, without opening it?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you've botched your profile up slightly by adding a custom command (something that runs as soon as it opens).

Thankfully you can edit your profile settings by running this (use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>):

```
gconf-editor /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default
```

If you've botched up too much you can use the Etch-a-Sketch method and reset everything back to defaults:

```
gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal/
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now! (PS. The site says that I can accept an answer in 2 minutes.)

Answer (score 5):

The command

```
gnome-terminal -e bash
```

will work around the profile command setting.

Once started, you can modify the profile.

Comment: This one works for me instead of the accepted answer.