# I accidentally made my terminal open another terminal when it starts. How can I fix it?

Tags: 10.04, command-line, gnome-terminal

I wanted to have it so that when I open a terminal, it is opened maximized. However I set the Default profile to open a terminal fullscreen when I open a terminal and... recursion.

The terminals open so fast that I can't access the profile options, and when I ctrl-C or ctrl-Z, nothing happens or if I do it faster, then ALL of the terminals close.

How can I fix this, without a terminal?

I'm using a Netbook remix of 10.04 I believe.

I made this change using the dropdown menu of an open Terminal. It opened a dialog box, I chose to edit the Default profile, and this opened another dialog box with multiple tabs, I changed to another tab and there was an option to "Run your own command" in which I put "gnome-terminal --window --maximize", thinking that this would REPLACE the current command that opens a terminal, not run it when a terminal opens.

SOLVED: Found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50035/how-to-open-the-terminal-mis-configured-the-profile), top answer worked. Summary: Run command using Alt-F2, use gconf-editor to uncheck the use-custom-command bool.

Comment: Confirm which **Ubuntu** version ..

Comment: What **settings** did you modify to cause this effect?

Comment: Added more info

Comment: If you have solved this, feel free to add your own answer and accept it. That is the norm here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50035/how-to-open-the-terminal-mis-configured-the-profile), top answer worked. Summary: Run command using Alt-F2, use gconf-editor to uncheck the use-custom-command bool.

Answer (score 0):

***I don't have 10.04 (Lucid) to test this on, but would suggest ..***

login in text-only mode, to this user, and type:

```
sudo rm -r ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal
```

When next login, Gnome Terminal should re-create default settings.

Answer (score 0):

you have to open `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/%gconf.xml` and search for the line starting with '`<entry name="use_custom_command"`' and change its value to false
[value=false]